# Array of 2 Data Types /MAP in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures

What I require is similar to array but for random numbers rather than (0,1,2,3.....).
I need to hold a number as the index/key and assign it a string.

For example student number, and then there name
So I could access `students[number]` and retrieve their name.

Similar to this code below but its in C++ and im using ANSI C

```
std::map <string, char> grade_list;
grade_list["John"] = 'B'
```

which was found here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/stlmap.html

I just cant seem to find away to solve this problem in ANSI C.

Can any one reccommend any way to produce this?

EDIT: Another point is the values of the table will be hard coded and do not required to be change so it's just a method with provides access to similar to...

`name[accesskey]` would return a string/data

GLIBS wont work because I'm using the compiler MINGW32 and there's problems using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GLib *Hash table* data structure.

http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Hash-Tables.html

Comment: thank you, this is what i was looking for , very surprised i didnt find this after a good hour of google'ing etc

Comment: Is there any hash tables there are as simple of GLIB but not that libary because my complier does have that libary as im using MINGW

Comment: If you can't use other libraries, you can write your own. If you have a small number, make a linked list. Otherwise you can do something like @wunind's answer, but use your own struct instead of `name` that also contains the IDs. You can then do linear search, or sort them and do binary search etc etc.

Comment: @ouah - we posted the same answer at the same time. I'm deleting mine, don't delete yours!

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
  int  valid;
  char name[32];
} Student;

Student students[100];

/* Initialize an element in the array. */
students[0].valid = 1;
strcpy(students[0].name, "Joe Blow");
```

Then write functions to find the first unused element, initializing one after finding it, and so on.

If you want to make it a bit more dynamic, you can instead use a dynamic array, something like this maybe:

```
typedef struct {
  size_t  allocated;
  Student *data;
} StudentRegistry;
```

and then use `realloc()` to make the array rooted at `data` grow when needed.

This all assumes that students are identified by their indices into the arrays, which seems to match the first part of your question ("student number"). This means student ID:s are "re-cycled" if e.g. a student is deleted.

**UPDATE**: If you want to choose your own ID:s, rather than use the ones "created" implicitly by indexing, then this approach is no good. I would then recommend a hash table. I like glib's.

Comment: But this doesn't address the OP's goal of indexing with arbitrary IDs instead of consecutive small integers.

Comment: This would be a suitable solutions if i was indexing like 1,2,3,4 but its more along the lines of 11 , 1 , 55,79,101 , thanks good solution

Comment: Is there anyway of doing this method but using my own key rather than small integers?